# Setting a primitive without getting a warning in Java

Tags: java

I have a Java method.  For the sake of being a public forum, I'm going to say that my method is called foo

```
Bar foo(Boolean flag)
{
   flag = true;
   return new Bar();
}
```

I get a warning by setting flag.  Unfortunately, I have not found a way to suppress such a warning.  Is there a "right" way of doing this?  Now I know there are some who will say to simply not use an out parameter.  Trust me when I say that I have a good reason for doing it this way.  If there's no way around the warning without doing something crazy, I suppose that's fine.  I just don't like checking in code with warnings.

Comment: `Boolean` is not a primitive. `boolean` is.

Comment: Please include the warning message in your question so that others can be sure they're commenting on the right issue.

Comment: Your example is abstracted to the point where it isn't clear what you're doing. If you truly just want to know how to suppress the warning, googling the warning text will probably yield an answer, if there is one. If you're interested in resolving the warning situation, you need to supply code more representative of your situation.

Comment: what about "Now I know there are some who will say to simply not use an out parameter." There is not such a thing as an out parameter in Java. Your flag will NOT change for the outside world! No code outside the method will know that the local value of parameter flag is true now.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "good reason for doing it this way"? What's the purpose of this code?

Comment: @PabloGrisafi I understand that Java doesn't have out parameters (nor a lot of other things as I'm discovering).  However, it communicated my purpose for passing the flag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're getting a warning because your assignment is doing nothing useful. You shouldn't check this code in because it doesn't do what you think it does. For example:

```
Boolean x = false;
Bar bar = foo(x);
System.out.println(x); // Still false
```

Your code is setting the value of the `flag` parameter, which won't change *anything* about the value which is passed in. Java *strictly* uses pass-by-value, including when it's passing reference (which it's doing here).

If `Boolean` were mutable you could write:

```
// Not actually valid
flag.setValue(true);
```

and change the contents of the object that `x` referred to in the first snippet of code - but all the wrapper types in Java are immutable.

Now it's not really clear what your higher level purpose is, but basically it's *not* going to be accomplished by the code you've given - so heed the warning, and change your approach.

Comment: ... +1 for reading OP's mind - probably correctly, given the "out parameter" thing.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  But I thought I'd throw out the question anyway to see if someone knew something that I didn't.

Comment: @Jason: Did you believe changing the parameter value had any effect? If you did, then folks *did* know something you didn't. If you already knew that, I'm intrigued to hear your "good reason for doing it this way".

Comment: No, I didn't realize that it wouldn't have any effect; but on hindsight I see that it does.  What I was afraid of was that there would be no way around the warning.  Turned out to be worse than I thought.  I come from a C# background.  So while I'm not a big fan of out parameters, in the scenario I'm working with, an out parameter would have been appropriate.

Comment: @Jason: In C# I'd probably have made the `Bar` an out parameter and returned a `bool`...

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the Java Annotations:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html

There is the "SuppressWarning" annotation that could help you.

Anyway, a good program shouldn't contain warnings ;)

Comment: Yep I agree with that statement. littering your code with bogus warnings will just hide from you the REAL warnings that might actually be useful

Comment: There's really never - never - any good reason to suppress a "Write to local variable that is never read" warning (whatever the official warning name is). After all it's a bug (or dead code, pick one)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am mistaken, but isn't there an exterior variable similar name to "flag"?
In that case it would make sense to adjust it, and use it as

```
this.setFlag(true)
```

or

```
this.flag = true;
```

in other details Jon gave good answer.